# Unable to merge dex - Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

Updated `gradle` and I guess that's what messed things up.
[image]

My gradle version is

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

    minSdkVersion = 14
    targetSdkVersion = 23
}
```

**build.gradle** inside of project ParseStarterProject
[image]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parse.starter"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    api 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    api 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

**Edit:** External Lib, please take a look, is this what's causing the issue?
[image]

Comment: In dependencies, Instead of compile call implementation, and also update to latest multidex version

Comment: It is usually sufficient to `Sync Project with Gradle files` or rebuild the project to solve this problem.

Comment: Don't use different versions of the google play services. You are using 11.8.0 and 9.4.0

Comment: @RobertK., I tried to use `implementation`. But still not working. Even multidex version.

Comment: @moictab, I tried Sync, clean, rebuild but still it's not working.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, Changed everything to 11.8.0. I got 7 errors now, figuring out how to make it work.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, completely true. but instead of upgrading, downgrading worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating your google play services may help you.
Latest is **11.8.0**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0
```

**clean** and **rebuild** your project

Comment: still facing the same problem.

Comment: I don't know how but things started working when I changed, `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0` to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0`.

Comment: As Gabrielle said, you are trying to use play services of ver 9.4.0 together with maps (which is already part of play services) of ver 11.8.0. therefore you can not have the same library in 2 different versions. Please don't include play services but rather only specific libraries that you need.